# Sql query to find Id tagged to multiple rows

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle10g

I have a student table with the below structure.

```
StudentId    StudentName     SubjectId
     123         Lina              1
     456         Andrews           4
     123         Lina              3 
     123         Lina              4
     456         Andrews           5
```

Need to write a query to get the studentId where the subjectid is equal to 1,3 and studentid is not equal to  4

```
Select studentId from student  where subject Id='1' and SubjectId ='3' and     
subjectId ='4' .
```

Output studentId should be 123

But it does not work out. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with grouping:

```
Select studentId 
from student  
where subject_Id in ('1', '3', '4')
group by studentId 
having count(distinct subject_Id) = 3
```

**Note:** You might consider changing `('1', '3', '4')` to `(1, 3, 4)` if `subject_Id` field is of type `int`.

**Note2:** `distinct` keyword inside `count` should be used in case you have duplicate  `subject_Id` values per `studentId`.

Comment: thank you for your reply. if I need to add the condition subjectid not equal to 4. How to modify the query

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be

```
select StudentId from student
where SubjectId in (1,3,4)
group by StudentId
having count(distinct SubjectId) = 3
```

Comment: hank you for your reply. if I need to add the condition subjectid not equal to 4. How to modify the query

Answer (score 0):

At once you can use only 1 subject id, for that your query must use or instead of and
 And don't use single course as well

Select studentId from student  where subject Id=1 or SubjectId =3 or
subjectId =4 .

Try this once